# ADO.NET escaping SQL without parameterization

Tags: ado.net

I'm trying to prove something to a friend of mine re: escaping SQL strings. What are the recommendations for escaping user-input parts of a SQL Server query when parameterization cannot be used (like when someone saves a chunk of SQL text in the database and it will be used as part of a where clause later)? Basically, it's a way to save pre-canned queries in a single text column. And even if he parameterized the where clause, it could potentially have an arbitrary number of parameters (that would still have to be stored in the database as text). Is there a way to do this that doesn't open up a SQL injection risk?

In this case, you can't really parameterize up front because you don't have a clean way of making sure that parameter names don't clash and the like. Is there some library in `System.Data.SqlClient` that just escapes strings to make them SQL safe without requiring parameterization? My buddy seems to think this is a thing and I don't, and I'm trying to keep him from stepping on himself. Oh, and to make things more fun, the SQL gets jammed into the database by .NET, but is executed dynamically by SQL Server, so there's no good way to rig it with EF or something like that either. For his approach to work, he'll have to sanitize the SQL some way.

Comment: Sanitizing SQL is a pain in the neck that have proved not useful long ago. Why store SQL statements in a database column? This entire designs smells so bad to me I had to open the window for some fresh air.  Tell your friend he should consult someone with architectural experience before moving forward.

Comment: It's stored that way so that another process can pick up a subset of records and process them later. Personally, I would store the expression tree in json in some manner and then build up the expression tree used to create the sql from that. Then it could be parameterized and sql injection risk could be avoided.

Comment: Does the SQL stored in the database contains any user input? if not, than SQL Injection is not likely....

Comment: It does, although the sql is built from a json payload coming out of a jquery querybuilder. But it seems to me that a malicious user could hand craft a payload that would get through and cause sql injection.